# Ionic Error: Cannot find module 'dezalgo'

Tags: ios, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, npm

i am trying to add the ios platform to my project so i can build it in XCode. I ran the following command: ionic cordova platform add ios

this is the error i got:

```
ionic cordova platform add ios
> cordova platform add ios --save
module.js:544
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'dezalgo'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:542:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:472:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:585:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/chando/Documents/GIT/testproject/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/correct-mkdir.js:2:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:641:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:652:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:560:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:503:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:495:3)
[ERROR] Exception:
```

i have tried multiple variations of deleting node_modules, installing the latest version of ionic, npm etc to no avail.

Has anyone else encountered this?

this is my ionic info:

cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : not installed
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.4
Cordova Platforms  : none
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Node  : v9.2.1
npm   : 5.6.0 
OS    : macOS Sierra
Xcode : Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue come up after updating to the latest Ionic/Angular for my project this morning. This a work-around, but it worked for me:

1. Add "dezalgo": "~1.0" to your devDependencies section of package.json
2. Run npm prune
3. Run npm install
4. Build your project

I can't tell you why it works other than to guess that somewhere in all of the NPM modules somebody forgot to include this dependency. I should also note that I updated my global modules as well, but I doubt that that would have had any influence on this.

Comment: Thanks. This fixed my issue. Yeah that's the only thing that makes sense

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Node.js 9.7.0 and npm 5.6.0.

Doing a clean install with `rm -rf node_modules && npm install` also solves this error.

At the time of writing, the issue is still not fixed. Numerous people are complaining about this `dezalgo` error on several GitHub issue boards:

- [nodejs/node #13492](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/13492)
- [npm/npm #8635](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8635)
- [npm/dezalgo #7](https://github.com/npm/dezalgo/issues/7)
- [tjunnone/npm-check-updates #420](https://github.com/tjunnone/npm-check-updates/issues/420)

EDIT: this issue seems to appear when one of the dependencies relies on an older npm version (such as [david](https://www.npmjs.com/package/david) or [npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates) packages).